# Using Python log lib, how to set the locale of the console StreamHandler?

Tags: python, logging, character-encoding, console

In my Python code I log to `stderr` and to a file with this configuration:

```py
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(asctime)s : %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler(
            my_network_folder / "publish.log"
        ),  
        logging.StreamHandler(),  # stderr
    ],
)
```

My problem is that sometimes it is run using [Rundeck](https://www.rundeck.com/) and displays a garbled console output. I have no way to control the rundeck encoding, so I'd like to change the encoding of StreamHandler for the encoding of Rundeck.

FileHandler has an `encoding`parameter, but I didn't find this option for the Stream handler. I'd like to do a `StreamHander(encoding='latin-1')`.

How can I set the console encoding?